# Lost desktop in Kali 2

Tags: linux, desktop, kali-linux, work-environment

I'm using kali 2 on a USB stick. I tried to install my favourite desktop environment cinnamon but something went wrong :-(

first I installed the cinnamon environment by

```
apt-get install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base cinnamon
```

then I tried to set the default environment with the following command:

```
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session session-name ‘cinnamon’
```

Now after rebooting I don't have a graphical environment any more. I have the default login screen from kali 2 but after login I've got the message:

> oh no! something has gome wrong. A problem has occurred and the system
>   can't recover. please log out and try again.

This last command gave me all the trouble so I need to revert this back to default or reconfigure the desktop environment back to default. Obviously I can make a new live USB drive but I really like to fix this problem. If you need more informatie (like logs/outputs) please ask. I still got a terminal and working internet.

Comment: Related question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224786/kali-linux-rpi-desktop-missing .

Answer (score 1):

Try running startx. If there is a error, post it here and create .xinitrc in your home directory and write in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
cinnamon
```

That should at least get you a desktop. Tell me if something else goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Just try apt-get install gnome. 
ctrl+alt+F3 if you can't use the terminal, sign in under root, and they try to install gnome.

Comment: Back in 2015 when this question was asked, Kali used KDE not Gnome, I don't believe this answer applies to the author's question.